# Android - How can I tell if the fb user change his/her profile pic

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'am creating an app the uses fb to register then getting its profile pic and name and save to my database then log-in you will see your profile pic and name(data came from database). .I already done that.

but the problem arise when I change my profile pic. . the image did not change after I log.in (of course it will not). I can't just ask a profile pic every log.in it will populate my server. .so what should I do? how can I tell if the fb user just changes his/her profile pic?

I'm hoping that the fb API

has something like this

```
image: fb.com/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx
Date_change : 11/25/2015
```

so that I can tell

Answer (score 0):

You can use Realtime Updates for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5#subscribefields

Subscribing to the "picture" field of the User object could work, for example.